# Labels and confidence level wont show on predicted results in YOLOv5 model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, yolo, yolov5

I am currently exploring YOLOv5 model for object detection. I have encountered a problem where the there is no labels and confidence level in the predicted results after training the model with our custom dataset.

Train command:
`!python train.py --batch 5 --epochs 100 --data custom_data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache`

Here is an image of the `val_batch0_labels.jpg` where the `val_batch0_pred.jpg` should almost be look like. [image: val_batch0_labels.jpg]

The predicted result `val_batch0_pred.jpg` looks like this.[image: val_batch0_labels.jpg]

It doesn't have label and confidence label on it. Does anyone know why is it?

I have also tried testing the trained weigh using this command:
`!python detect.py --weights runs/train/exp7/weights/best.pt --img 128 --conf 0.25 --source ../Test1.png`, but the result also doesn't have label on it

I am using Google Collab